# What does "both" refer to in "...holding a baby in her arms, both shaking"?

Tags: pronouns, adjuncts

> Then he noticed the woman, who'd helped him earlier, gently holding a baby in her arms, **both** shaking.

(A sentence from my workbook)

Does this sentence work well? What (or who) does "both" refer to: arms, the woman, baby, or writer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't decide this grammatically, you can only decide this *pragmatically*.  That is you need to use your common knowledge and common sense.

*You* are qualified to do this - it doesn't require any special skills in English.  What makes more sense in the context of the whole story? Which would you find unsurprising? Which is rather ridiculous?

1. The woman and the baby were both shaking.
2. The woman's left and right arms were both shaking.

Comment: Actually, I think you need to apply [Grice's four maxims of conversation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cooperative_principle), not just *What makes more sense in context?* Logically, since they're all "physically connected" it's incredibly likely that the two arms *and* the baby will all shake even if the mother is only applying muscle power to one arm (or if the mother isn't making any effort, and the *baby* is causing the shaking. So we have to ask why the speaker would bother to mention ***both*** shaking. A likely reason being that both mother *and* baby are contributing motive power.

Comment: ...but as you say, *it doesn't require any special skills in English* to decide that. The Gricean maxims are language-independent.

Comment: I agree with you, although I also think the sentence is kind of badly written because it's clearer to put a phrase near what it modifies, and here *arms* is awkwardly stuck in between (woman holding baby) and (both shaking).

Comment: @stangdon: It often happens that querents here are saddled with poor quality example text (often written by non-native Anglophones to save money, I suspect). Because I personally wouldn't have included the commas offsetting ***who'd helped him earlier***, I just threw those words at Google Books. I wasn't surprised to find that not one of the 11 instances returned has those commas.

Comment: @FumbleFingers  Thanks and you are right that work books are usually not written by native speakers. That's why I ask firstly if the sentence works well.